# How can i read the end of a file in c#?

Tags: c#, file

i searched in stackoverflow and got one way but this method only let me to write word by word in the console. My goal is to get the end of my file but get the complete result not char by char.

This code only show me char by char the end of my file:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader("file.dll")
{
    if (reader.BaseStream.Length > 1024)
    {
        reader.BaseStream.Seek(-1024, SeekOrigin.End);
    }

    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

I was trying to get something like this, it's c++ but i was trying to get the same result in c#.

```
QFile *archivo;
archivo = new QFile();
archivo->setFileName("file.dll");
archivo->open(QFile::ReadOnly);
archivo->seek(archivo->size() - 1024);
trama = archivo->read(1024);
```

It's possible to get the complete result of the end of my file in c#?

Answer (score 2):

If the file is line-delimited text file, you can use [ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("file.txt");
```

If it's a binary file, you can use [ReadAllBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx). Shocker, I know.

```
byte[] data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("file.dll");
```

if you want to be able to seek first (e.g. if you want only the last 1024 bytes of the file) you can use the stream's [Read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kstw824(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Again, crazy.

```
reader.BaseStream.Seek(-1024, SeekOrigin.End);
var chars = new char[1024];
reader.Read(chars, 0, 1024);
```

And before you ask, you can convert the characters to a string by passing them to the constructor:

```
char[] chars = new char[1024];
string s = new string(chars);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Not sure what it'll look like, since you're reading characters from a binary file, but good luck. My guess is you should be reading bytes instead though:

```
reader.BaseStream.Seek(-1024, SeekOrigin.End);
var bytes = new byte[1024];
reader.BaseStream.Read(bytes, 0, 1024);
```

(Notice you don't even need the StreamReader, since the FileStream (your base stream) exposes the Read method you need).

Comment: and if it's a dll?

Comment: Maybe try `ReadAllBytes()`? Crazy enough it just might work.

Comment: but i want to read the last bytes for this the seek function and the example works just char by char i need to show it like a complete string of my last bytes.

Comment: maybe i must to use var value = reader.ReadToEnd(); instead of while

Comment: for reading the last byte of the fite, all you need is to use a stream.